# What can I do about a malicious site with a similar domain name?

Tags: web-application, domain

I recently purchased a domain name (lets pretend it was generic.co), I checked to see what site was hosted on the domain close to mine (generic.com).  The site loads a fake blue screen of death and has a JavaScript modal that can't be dismissed.

This is obviously some sort of malware distribution vector. Is there anything I can do to get this site shutdown?

Comment: Be more careful choosing your next domain name and register nearby names as well. It's still difficult. gooogle.com is a malware site (according to zscaler). So even the big boys have problems with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have definite proof that malware is being distributed from there, you might get the hoster to shutdown the website. Other than that, the person who has generic.com has every right to host anything that he wants on it.

Unless its a really specific domain name that is completely unique and you have reason to believe it was created to distribute malware to your users, you don't have a realistic chance of getting it shutdown.

Comment: Suspected that might be the case.  Used whois to find the registrar, looks like the have domain privacy active.  Reaching out to the registrar, not the domain privacy company is the next move, right?

Comment: As the answerer mentions, you might want to contact the host to report that their hosting service is being used to host malware.  Do a DNS lookup for the domain name, and that should return the IP address of the web server that is hosting the site.  Then, do a whois lookup on that IP, and that should tell you who the host is.